# There was an error exporting the layer from ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, export, error

When trying to do export a layer to create anther shapefile I receive this message:
It's only giving me this message for this layer. I tried on another layer and it seemed to work.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.

[image]

Comment: When you performed the export you would have set parameters on a tool dialog.  Would you be able to edit your question to include a picture of those settings, please?

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información para solucionar este inconveniente!!
regards!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this method, it could be work.

1. using "copy feature" tool to create a new feature class in .gdb.
2. export the new feature as a shapefile.

Comment: Thanks Julia and PolyGeo.
I copied the feature and then exported it with no problems. The only downside is that ArcGIS online only allows the import of 1000 features per shapefile. My ultimate map has to be downsized unfortunately.